# Electron - Path recognized before compiling into .exe but not after

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I try to launch my Electron app while debugging (before compiling) it works without any issues. Its purpose is to execute a powershell script that activates a python venv, runs the python program, and then prints the python logger messages inside the Electron app.

When I compile it however it prints "undefined" instead of the expected result. I have tried double-checking the paths and it works both *before* compiling and *after* IF I run the source code directly in `resources -> app -> src` folder. So what's going on here?

I am spawning a child process in `app.js` like so:

```js
// Starts the app.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    win = createWindow()

    // Handles minimize functionality.
    ipcMain.on('min-app', () => {win.minimize()})

    // Handles quit functionality.
    ipcMain.on('quit-app', () => {app.quit();});

    // Handles running Python scripts in venvs, which is why PS is used.
    ipcMain.on('run-script', () => {
        // Spawns a PS process, which allows activation of the venv before running the Python program.
        let script = nodeChildProcess.spawn('powershell.exe', ['.\\src\\execute_python.ps1']);
        let loggerMsgs = '';
        let utils = new UtilityFunctions();

        // This is the only way to ensure getting log messages in the correct order.
        script.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
        script.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
            loggerMsgs += chunk;
        });

        // Handles the logic of splitting the string and sending the data to the renderer.
        script.on('close', (_code, _signal) => {
            // Dictionary of log messages with 2 keys: 'Levels' and 'Contents'.
            messages = utils.splitLogMessages(loggerMsgs);

            // Send to renderer.
            win.webContents.send('update-log', messages);
        });
    });
}).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
```

I have tried changing the path from `.\\src\\execute_python.ps1` to `.\\resources\\app\\src\\execute_python.ps1` but this doesn't work either when running the compiled .exe.

`execute_python.ps1` is very simple and looks like this:

```ps1
Set-Location "src\python-package"
.\Scripts\activate
python .\script.py
```

[Folder structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0SfL.png).

**Expected output:**
[Before clicking "kør"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yrVx.png) 
[After clicking "kør"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9udPm.png)

**Actual output:**
[Before clicking "kør"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htDfy.png)
[After clicking "kør"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghRFn.png)

**NOTE:** I am currently only testing the logger level, so it is to be expected that the logger content (the non-green text) doesn't change. The Python log messages are structured like this: `[  INFO  ] - 17:23 info mesg here`